# regex to find a word or words between spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find the words in a sentence between spaces. So the words till the first space  before and after the search word

`This is anexampleof what I want` should return `anexampleof` if my search word is `example`

I now have this regex `"(?:^|\S*\s*)\S*" + searchword + "\S*(?:$|\s*\S*)"` but this gives me an extra word in the beginning and the end.
'This is anexampleof what I want' --> returns 'is anexampleof what'

I tried to change the regex but I'm not good at it at all..
I'm using c#. Thx for the help.

Full C# code:

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(content, @"(?:^|\S*\s*)\S*" + searchword + @"\S*(?:$|\s*\S*)",
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Alright, what do you expect if your content is this? `This is an exampleof what I want` or `This is anexample of what I want` or `This is an example of what I want`. Can you show in each of these what your expected output is? It would have been simple enough if you could say, I need the word that contains my keyword? If the keyword doesn't contain between two words, what do you expect? :) correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: N.B. Replace `+ searchword +` with [`+ Regex.Escape(searchword) +`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) if you're at all worried about your users passing in special regex characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply leave out the non-capturing groups at the end:

```
@"\S*" + searchword + @"\S*";
```

Due to greediness you will get as many non-space characters on each side as possible.

Also, the idea of non-capturing groups is not, that they are not included in the match. All they do is not to produce captures of sub-matches. If you wanted to check that there is something, but don't to include it in the match, you want [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@"(?<=^|\S*\s*)\S*" + searchword + @"\S*(?=$|\s*\S*)"
```

However these lookarounds don't really do anything in this case, because `\s*\S*` is satisfied with an empty string (because `*` makes both characters optional). But just for further reference... if you want to make assertions at the boundary of your match, which should not be part of the match... lookarounds are the way to go.

Comment: That looks like it does it too. Now I was further testing myself and I found this to work also but I think your solution is way simpler:  MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(content, @"(?:^|\S*\s*)" + searchword + @"(?:$|\s*\S*)",
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline); Thx!

Comment: @Stieven76 if your input is `This is an example of what I want` your last pattern would return `an example of`.